# Converting a phonenumber from file into a new format

Tags: c, io

I am trying to convert a series of phone number written in various ways, such as:

```
324.323 4345
234-345-6456.
```

The format I want to convert them to is: `(xxx) xxx-xxxx`

Here is the code i have so far, unfortunately it doesn't work..

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main() {

    FILE *fp;
    char str[31], ch;
    int i = 0, p1, p2, p3;
    fp = fopen("numbers.txt", "r");


        while((ch = getc(fp)) != '\n')
       {
 if(isdigit(ch))
                str[i++] = ch;
        str[i] = '\0';
        i = 0;

        sscanf(str, "%3d%3d%4d", &p1, &p2, &p3);
        printf("(%3d) %3d-%4d\n", p1, p2, p3);
      }
fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

What am i doing wrong here? I know i probably need to isolate each integer but am having issues doing that.

Just ran it using the following:

```
 404.817.6900
 (215)  686-1776
312-746-6000
877 275 5273
6173434200
```

and got the following:

```
(  4) 4196261-32767
(  0) 4196261-32767
(  4) 4196261-32767
(  4) 4196261-32767
(  8) 4196261-32767
(  1) 4196261-32767
(  7) 4196261-32767
(  7) 4196261-32767
(  6) 4196261-32767
(  9) 4196261-32767
(  0) 4196261-32767
(  0) 4196261-32767
(  0) 4196261-32767
```

Comment: In what way does it not work? What's the problem? For a file containing two lines with the input you provided and no leading/trailing characters, it works (linux).

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis It runs, however it doesnt display the right stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will this work for you?  It has three bites at the cherry, so to speak (in the worst case):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char buffer[128];

    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin) != 0)
    {
        int p1, p2, p3;
        if (sscanf(buffer, "%*[^0-9]%3d%*[^0-9]%3d%*[^0-9]%4d", &p1, &p2, &p3) == 3 ||
            sscanf(buffer, "%3d%*[^0-9]%3d%*[^0-9]%4d", &p1, &p2, &p3) == 3 ||
            sscanf(buffer, "%3d%3d%4d", &p1, &p2, &p3) == 3)
            printf("(%3d) %3d-%4d from %s", p1, p2, p3, buffer);
        else
            printf("Failed to convert %s", buffer);
    }
    return(0);
}
```

For your test data set, I get:

```
(404) 817-6900 from  404.817.6900
(215) 686-1776 from  (215)  686-1776
(312) 746-6000 from 312-746-6000
(877) 275-5273 from 877 275 5273
(617) 343-4200 from 6173434200
```

Comment: Cool, But how would you have it read from a file instead of having the user input it?

Comment: I used `./x < data` so the program read it from the file which it was given as standard input.  I certainly didn't type your data out (long live copy'n'paste).  Using your program as the basis, I'd open the file as you do, check that it worked (as you don't but should), and then simply replace `fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin)` with `fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp)`; the rest of my loop would remain unchanged (unless you decided to drop the printing of the input buffer).

Answer (score 2):

I would probably start with something like this:

```
if (3 == sscanf(str, "%3d%*[^0-9]%3d%8[^0-9]%4d", &p1, &p2, &p3))
    printf("(%3d) %3d-%4d\n", p1, p2, p3);
```

The "%*[^0-9]" parts skip across anything else until they get to the next digit.

Edit: I hadn't noticed that one of the possible inputs has no separation between the digits at all. Unfortunately, you can't really limit `scanf`'s integer conversion to only reading the first three digits, or something like that. To deal with that, you pretty much need to read a string instead of a number. To keep the code a little more comprehensible, I'd also break it up into a few pieces instead of trying to read all of it at once, giving something like this:

```
int copy_num(FILE *file, FILE *out) { 
    char p1[4], p2[4], p3[5];
    int ret=0;

    fscanf(file, "%*[^0-9]");
    ret += fscanf(file, "%3s%*[^0-9]", p1);
    ret += fscanf(file, "%3s%*[^0-9]", p2);
    ret += fscanf(file, "%4s", p3);
    if (ret == 3)
        fprintf(out, "(%3s) %3s-%4s\n", p1, p2, p3);
    return ret == 3;
}
```

Comment: Where is the 3 coming from?

Comment: Presumably you mean the `3` in `if (3==...`. The return value from `sscanf` is the number of fields it converted successfully, so this is checking that the three fields we asked it to convert were, in fact, all converted successfully.

Comment: I put that in the code i have and now it prints nothing at all.

Comment: @user1855131: Oops -- stupid typo ("%8" where I intended "%*"). `sscanf(buffer, "%*[^0-9]%3d%*[^0-9]%3d%*[^0-9]%4d", &p1, &p2, &p3);` will be at least a bit better -- but it still won't work your last example, with the digits all mashed together. To deal with that, you'll just about need to read strings instead of ints.

Comment: How/where should i use the `if (3 == sscanf `  if I replace what i currently have it doesnt do anything. Thanks, Im just trying to get a better idea of how to do this.

Comment: @user1855131: I've edited the answer to give a little better idea.

Comment: cool, thanks. How would i pass the file info and stuff to that function? is it the same as i would normally do it if i got user input? or is it different for i/o?

Comment: Just pass `fp=fopen(...); copy_num(fp, stdout);` to read from `fp` and write to `stdout`.

Comment: Note that `"%3d%3d%4d"` does work on a string of 10 digits, splitting correctly.

Answer (score 0):

in https://github.com/iziz/libPhoneNumber-iOS

Below code

```
NBPhoneNumberUtil *phoneUtil = [NBPhoneNumberUtil sharedInstance];

NSError *aError = nil;
NBPhoneNumber *myNumber = 
    [phoneUtil parse:@"6766077303" defaultRegion:@"AT" error:&aError];

if (aError == nil) {
    // Should check error
    NSLog(@"isValidPhoneNumber ? [%@]", 
        [phoneUtil isValidNumber:myNumber] ? @"YES":@"NO");
    NSLog(@"E164          : %@", [phoneUtil format:myNumber 
                                      numberFormat:NBEPhoneNumberFormatE164 
                                             error:&aError]);
    NSLog(@"INTERNATIONAL : %@", [phoneUtil format:myNumber
                                      numberFormat:NBEPhoneNumberFormatINTERNATIONAL 
                                             error:&aError]);
    NSLog(@"NATIONAL      : %@", [phoneUtil format:myNumber 
                                      numberFormat:NBEPhoneNumberFormatNATIONAL 
                                             error:&aError]);
    NSLog(@"RFC3966       : %@", [phoneUtil format:myNumber  
                                      numberFormat:NBEPhoneNumberFormatRFC3966 
                                             error:&aError]);
}
else {
    NSLog(@"Error : %@", [aError localizedDescription]);
}
```

will return it

```
isValidPhoneNumber ? [YES]
E164          : +436766077303
INTERNATIONAL : +43 676 6077303
NATIONAL      : 0676 6077303
RFC3966       : tel:+43-676-6077303
```